# piping commands not working as expected I need explanation

Tags: files, pipe, cat

I am trying to do the below

```
touch ~/scratches/scr6.txt | cat ~/scr.txt > ~/scratches/scr6.txt | cat /dev/null > ~/scr.txt
```

I don't know why scr6.txt is always empty, however doing the below fill up the file

```
cat ~/scr.txt > ~/scratches/scr6.txt
```

I wonder why the first case is not working?

Comment: The `touch` command is the way to create new, _empty files_.

Comment: Why the pipes ?  touch doesn't generate any output, so why pipe it to cat, where cat isn't reading anything from the stdin pipe ?

Comment: It would be better if you explain what are you trying to achieve. This chain of commands doesn't make much sense.

Comment: So what did you expect actually?

Comment: Hello I am trying to create a file copy the content of file 1 into a folder under different name and then clear the content of file 1

Comment: I should use && instead of | thanks to @steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking down each of the steps:

- `touch ~/scratches/scr6.txt`

  If file exists, updates the timestamp to now.  If doesn't exist, creates it.
- `cat ~/scr.txt > ~/scratches/scr6.txt`

  Reads ~/scr.txt and writes the contents to ~scratches/scr6.txt
- `cat /dev/null > ~/scr.txt`

  Empties the ~/scr.txt file

As mentioned in the comments, using "&&" (AND) between the commands instead of "|" (PIPE) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Pretty close, except that it doesn't really happen in that order, necessarily. The `|` pipes and `scr.txt` and `scr6.txt` are all created *first* by the shell. Both of the txt files are truncated at creation time. The commands run in the pipelines are all started up concurrently. It's why the middle `cat` doesn't complain that `scr6.txt` isn't there - because the shell took care of all redirections on its own before calling up any of the commands.

Comment: @mikeserv thanks for the feedback.  The use of pipes for this strikes me as odd/pointless/confusing, why not just join them all together with &&  instead of | ?

Comment: @steve I will accept your answer if you mentioned use && instead of pipes. I was not aware of && thanks

Answer (score 2):

Okay, considering that `scr.txt` file contains some text before executing command and `scr6.txt` doesn't exist yet: the command

```
touch ~/scratches/scr6.txt | cat ~/scr.txt > ~/scratches/scr6.txt | cat /dev/null > ~/scr.txt
```

1. Empty `scr.txt` file (`cat /dev/null > ~/scr.txt`)
2. Overrides `scr6.txt` with contetns of `scr.txt` (nothing) (`cat ~/scr.txt > ~/scratches/scr6.txt`)
3. Does nothing because `scr6.txt` already exists (`touch ~/scratches/scr6.txt`)

But the following command

```
cat ~/scr.txt > ~/scratches/scr6.txt
```

Just writes `scr.txt` contents to `scr6.txt`

So that's why both files are empty in 1st case and everything works like expected in 2nd case.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, piped processes all start more-or-less at the same time. Generally, the processes in a pipeline will read from stdin or write to stdout (or both), and completion of the I/O will dictate when the process ends.

For processes that don't have any output (like `touch`) or any standard input (like `cat` when operating on a file), I would generally expect that their pipe connections would just be ignored by the program.

So what you would basically have is three commands running in parallel:

`touch ~/scratches/scr6.txt`,
`cat ~/scr.txt > ~/scratches/scr6.txt`,
and `cat /dev/null > ~/scr.txt`.

It's probably OS-dependent whether command 2 would fail with an error if ~/scr.txt doesn't already exist, since it would be in a race condition with command 3. Commands 1 and 2 are also in a race condition, but the race would only wind up affecting the file's ctime/mtime/atime.

Answer (score -1):

In simple words:

The `touch` command is the way to create new, *empty files*. It is also used to change the timestamps (i.e., dates and times of the most recent access and modification) on existing files and directories.

In the first command it creates an empty file named `scr6.txt`.

But in second command it create a file `scr6.txt` and writes all the contents of `scr.txt` to this file.

Comment: That's the anticipated result, OP is asking why that isn't occurring

Comment: OP has mentioned _I don't know why scr6.txt is always empty_, so I guess he is not aware about `touch` command. And my answer explain that. OP has not mentioned what (s)he is expecting.